# Applying -lt on string variables in bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting, string

I am new to bash scripting. I have to compare two values here, $i and $cdsStart: check if $i is lesser than $cdsScript, below is my code for doing the same.

```
inputFile="$1"
while read -r transcriptName chromosomeNum strand transcriptStart transcriptEnd cdsStart cdsEnd numExons exSt exEnd rest ;
do
  if [ "$transcriptName" == "ENST00000359033" ]
  then
     exonStart=$(echo "$exSt" | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
     exonEnd=$(echo "$exEnd" | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
     echo "exon-start: $exonStart"
     echo "exon-end: $exonEnd"

     for i in "$exonStart"
     do
      if (( "$i" -lt "$cdsStart" ))  ##this does not work
      then
        echo "value: $i"    
      fi    
    done
  fi
done < "$inputFile"
```

It just reports "syntax error in expression", can someone tell me how to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: It will not work, use `<`  see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html

Comment: In bash, `(( ))` is an arithmetic expression; its operators and syntax are different from those in a `[ ]` test or a `[[ ]]` conditional expression.

Answer (score 0):

#### Can someone tell me how to debug this?

Use [ShellCheck – shell script analysis tool](https://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
inputFile="$1"
^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.

Line 2:
while read -r transcriptName chromosomeNum strand transcriptStart transcriptEnd cdsStart cdsEnd numExons exSt exEnd rest ;
                             ^-- SC2034: chromosomeNum appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                                           ^-- SC2034: strand appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
                                                  ^-- SC2034: transcriptStart appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
>>                                                                ^-- SC2034: transcriptEnd appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
>>                                                                                       ^-- SC2034: cdsEnd appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).
>>                                                                                              ^-- SC2034: numExons appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Line 6:
     exonStart=$(echo "$exSt" | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
                                ^-- SC2196: egrep is non-standard and deprecated. Use grep -E instead.

Line 7:
     exonEnd=$(echo "$exEnd" | egrep -o '[0-9]+')
                               ^-- SC2196: egrep is non-standard and deprecated. Use grep -E instead.

Line 11:
     for i in "$exonStart"
              ^-- SC2066: Since you double quoted this, it will not word split, and the loop will only run once.

Line 13:
      if (( "$i" -lt "$cdsStart" ))  ##this does not work
         ^-- SC1105: Shells disambiguate (( differently or not at all. For subshell, add spaces around ( . For ((, fix parsing errors.
          ^-- SC2205: (..) is a subshell. Did you mean [ .. ], a test expression?
                 ^-- SC1106: In arithmetic contexts, use < instead of -lt
```